# Python scan directory and eliminate duplicate directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, os.walk, os.path

I have to scan directory recursively with limited deepest value . I am achieving this using OS module. Below is the code

```
scan_dir = "/a/b/c"
import os

def walk(top, maxdepth):
    dirs, nondirs = [], []
    for name in os.listdir(top):
        (dirs if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(top, name)) else nondirs).append(os.path.join(top,name))
    yield top, dirs, nondirs
    if maxdepth > 1:
        for name in dirs:
            for x in walk(os.path.join(top, name), maxdepth-1):
                yield x

for x in walk(scan_dir, 2):
    _, dir_list, nondirs_list = x
    dirs_final = dirs_final + dir_list
    nondirs_final = nondirs_final + nondirs_list
```

Because we are getting out of memory, if we scan /a/b/c since it has lot of  files (below code scan fuction we are using just fyi) to fix issue memory issue, I thought to scan smaller sub  directories 4 level deepest.

```
from pathlib import Path
def scan(path):
    for Entry in Path(path).iterdir():
        if Entry.is_dir() and not Entry.is_symlink():
            yield Entry
            for SubEntry in scan(Entry):
                yield SubEntry
        else:
            yield Entry
```

now All sub directories are present in dirs_final, but it contains following paths

```
   example: /a/b/c/d
            /a/b/c/d/e/f/g
            /a/b/c/d/e/f
```

In above case we are scanning "/a/b/c/d/e/f/g" 3 times, one during /a/b/c/d, another

/a/b/c/d/e/f and other /a/b/c/d/e/f/g

How to avoid this duplicates in dirs_final list and so that I will only scanning One time

Answer (score 0):

You can use set() as output:

```
def walk( root, dirs, files, max_depth=4, depth=0 ):
    try:
        for node in os.listdir( root ):
            full_path = os.path.join( root, node )
            # skip symlinks
            if os.path.islink( full_path ):
                continue
            if os.path.isfile( full_path ): 
                files.add( node )
            else:
                # print( full_path )
                dirs.add( node )    
                if depth < max_depth:
                    walk( full_path, dirs, files, max_depth, depth=depth+1 )
    except Exception as errors:
        pass # print( errors )
```

usage :

```
dirs    = set()
files   = set()

walk( '/usr/bin', dirs, files )
```

Comment: if we add full path and then same issue